# How to insert multiple html input field data in an php array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-input

***Here is the html input part of my code:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="subject" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

***User will click fill that form multiple times to insert multiple 'subjects'.Each time the input field value will be stored inside an array.When the user adds another 'subject',it will be stored in the next index of the array.

***Here is what I have so far regarding my PHP end.

```
$i=0; //this is declared globally at the beginning of my page;before html tag                   

$array=array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$array[$i]=$subject;
$i=$i+1;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your question **multiple html input field**??

Comment: I am using only one input field but user will post data multiple times through one input field.And every time it will be saved in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store your 'subjects' into the session, so you can easily put and get what you want.

```
<?php
    session_start();    // THIS IS FOR SUPERGLOBAL VARIABLE $_SESSION

    $i=0;     

    // THIS STORES YOU INDEX '$i'
    if(!isset($_SESSION['index']))
    {
        $_SESSION['index'] = 0;
    }else{
        $i = $_SESSION['index'];
    }       

    if(!isset($_SESSION['array']))
    {
        $_SESSION['array'] = array();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $_SESSION['array'][$i] = $subject;
        $_SESSION['index'] = $i + 1;
    }
?>
```

This should work for you ;)

Comment: had to add  session_destroy(), otherwise it was storing value from each session! but works perfectly for me, so it's the way to go! thanks a lot man :)

Comment: You are welcome Muktadir. Just put session_destroy() where you want to delete the stored array values. For example with a button that makes a POST request to a page that handles the event and destroys the session.